# Is it safe to enable password sync on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: passwords, web-browser

Microsoft Edge, as well as other Chromium browsers, have a password sync feature built into their browsers, which look something like the image below.

Before I enable this feature for convenience and being able to sync my passwords across my macOS, iOS, and Windows devices, I want to be sure that it's safe. In particular, I have the following question:

- Could a bad actor hack the password database from the browser directly? Perhaps this might be harder on macOS than Windows?
- Can I trust that Microsoft will not hold the decryption keys to my passwords?
- Can I trust that there are no backdoors or security loopholes in this password storage? Companies like AgileBytes focus on data security—would a web browser have the same level of protection?

[image]